# Insert value to db based on a condition using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-insert

I'm developing a small quiz that saves the participants information into a db and based on quiz results I save a status that has to be 0 for not answering correctly and a 1 for correct answers. 
I think I made some mistakes somewhere, and I'm new to javascript and need some advice.
Here is my code for inserting  into the database:

```
function setUserInfofunction(Email, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME,COMPANY ,PHONE, STATUS) {
        var result = WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
            preparedStatement: setUserInfo, parameters : [Email,FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, COMPANY,PHONE, STATUS]
        });
        return result;
```

};

Here is the code for the part where it is supposed to validate the result of the quiz and give the user a status:

```
function validation(){

if (answers[0]==choices[0][0]  &&  answers[1]==choices[1][1]  &&  answers[2]==choices[2][2] && answers[2] == choices[2][1] )
{
      setUserInfo = parameters (status = '1');
    } 
else {
    setUserInfo = parameters (status = '0');
}
}
if (answers[0]==choices[0][0]  ||  answers[1]==choices[1][1]  ||  answers[2]==choices[2][2] || answers[2] == choices[2][1])
{
      setUserInfo = parameters (status = '0');

}
else {
    setUserInfo = parameters (status = '1');
}
```

Comment: a client sided logic ( javascript ) should write on a centralized database directly? Please never EVER do stuff like that. Rather use javascript to make the gui nice and sweet and one of the "hundreds" server logic languages ( php, python, asp... ) to handle the rest

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question...